# Android: Error , Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor , t_forms that has not been deactivated or closed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a DB  helper class that helps me insert and delete records of pieces of information in Android 1.6.

When I delete a record and insert a new one just after that, i get the following error

Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d63338 on t_forms that has not been deactivated or closed

I have gone through the web searching for an answer, and most forum posts say that a cursor is not closed.In fact the operations I am executing aren't really returning recordset data, so I am a little stumped on why logcat would throw this error...

So these are the 2 functions that get called one after the other..

```
//---deletes a particular form---
public boolean deleteForm(int formID) 
{
   return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_FORM_ID + "=" + formID, null) > 0;
}

//---insert a form into the database---
public long insertForm(int form_id, String lform_name, String lform_description, String sdcardPath) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_FORM_ID, form_id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FORM_NAME, lform_name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FORM_DESC, lform_description);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SDCARDPATH, sdcardPath);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The code you've provided is not enough to say where exactly the error originates.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is not enough. But first close the cursor in onDestroy and onStop like this:

```
if(mCursor!= null && !mCursor.isClosed())
   mCursor.close();
```

and then try calling `startManagingCursor(cursor)` after where you use your cursor object, if you use it to make a query, etc, call it after the operation you make with the cursor.